# There is already a theorem that demonstrates this inequality?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology

I would like to create my first paper on math, this time in geometry, and the intuitive definition of the theorem would be that:

> A 2D disk with radius $r$ and a continuous function (for example, a mountain) that forms a disk with radius $r$ seen from the top, fixed at the exact centre, will always have a greater surface than the initial disk it is placed above.

Here there are two images: a red disk and a red mountain. The point would be that the mountain always has greater surface/area than the disk for a fixed area (marked as red):

The Disk:
[image: Disk]

The Mountain:
[image: Mountain]

I am thinking of demonstrating it with integrals and polar coordinates. I'll also highen it to $n$ dimensions.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is your question?

Comment: As stated the wording doesn’t really make sense. But I guess you’re trying to show that the surface area of the graph of a function (in your case the upper hemisphere) is atleast the surface area of the domain (disk in your case)? If this is what you would like to show then, assuming the function is $C^1$ rather than just continuous, you can indeed prove this using the integral formula for surface area, in just one line.

Comment: Yes. The idea is that a flat disk will always have a lower surface/area than a mountain, for example, that would be placed above it and that is bounded by the region of the disk.

Comment: It works with any domain, not only a disk because it is a local result. The infinitesimal area on the given surface is equal to the projected area divided by the cosine of the angle between the tangent plane of the surface and the xy plane.

Comment: I don't know any precise reference but I'm sure this theorem is at least 200 years old.

Comment: It sounds a bit like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality

Comment: @AntonioPeña In 2D that's the triangle inequality. How to prove it in 3D it depends on the context and assumptions you work with.

Comment: I think this is a nice inequality to conjecture and prove for yourself. You may even want to write it up carefully as practice. It isn't a publishable result, and it's probably not the kind of paper you were advised to write. But it's a good exercise nonetheless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\Omega\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ be any non-empty open set, and $f:\Omega\to\Bbb{R}$ a $C^1$ function. Then, for any (Lebesgue-measurable) set $E\subset \Omega$, the $n$-dimensional surface area of the portion of the graph of $f$ which lies over $E$ is given by
\begin{align}
S(\Gamma_{f,E})=\int_E\sqrt{1+\|\nabla f\|^2}\,dx.
\end{align}
THis is a standard formula from advanced calculus (the 1D analogue is $\int_a^b\sqrt{1+[f’(x)]^2}\,dx$ for the length of the graph of a function $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$).
Compare with the $n$-dimensional area of the region $E$ itself, which is simply
\begin{align}
\lambda(E)&=\int_E1\,dx.
\end{align}
Which is bigger? Obviously it is the first because of monotonicity of integrals (i.e $\|\nabla f\|^2\geq 0$ and therefore $\sqrt{1+\|\nabla f\|^2}\geq 1$, so integrating over $E$ still keeps the same inequality). So, we have
\begin{align}
\text{$n$-dimensional surface area of graph of $f$ lying over $E$}&\geq \text{$n$-dimensional area of $E$},
\end{align}
and the proof is simply a one-line inequality. In simpler words, the mountain has larger surface area than the disk. But as you can see above, the statement holds quite generally, and is not specific to disks.

In fact the proof tells us that equality holds for all sets $E$ if and only if $\nabla f=0$ identically on $\Omega$, which happens if and only if the function $f$ is constant (on each connected component of $\Omega$).

---

**Final Remarks.**

I’m not sure what level you’re at mathematically, but seeing as this is such a simple inequality, it certainly doesn’t warrant a paper. If this is some sort of high-school project, maybe talk about where the formula for surface area comes from? And why such an inequality is useful/interesting. Now, I actually can’t think of anything useful to say about this particular inequality since it is too obvious, but the isoperimetric inequality is a much more non-trivial and interesting inequality.

Ok, to make things slightly non-trivial, one should weaken hypotheses on the function $f$. For example, continuous $f$ or something else. In this case, a-priori it’s not even clear how to define the surface area, and this could be an interesting thing to write a short paper about (but beware, you can quickly run into very abstract measure-theoretic technicalities).

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{1 + \|\nabla f\|^2} = \frac{1}{\cos\theta}$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the tangent hyperplane to the graph of $f$ in ${\mathbb R}^{n+1}$ and the hyperplane ${\mathbb R}^n\subset {\mathbb R}^{n+1}$.

Comment: In fact, I needed to prove an inequality of this short for another paper in physics. Nonetheless, as one scholar recommended me to write as many papers as I could on a given topic from every idea, then I thought of creating another one just for this little theorem. I'm first-year student of Data Science hehe. I'll try to make it as non-trivial as possible. Thanks a million for the demonstration and remarks!

Comment: Perhaps the most general version of this statement is that for any subset $S$ of $\Bbb{R}^n$ and any $d$ the $d$-dimensional Hausdorff measure of $S$ is at least as large as the  $d$-dimensional Hausdorff measure of the projection of $S$ onto $\Bbb{R}^m$ for any $m \leq n$.

Comment: @Fishbane yea I was implicitly alluding to the Hausdorff measure in my last sentence. But of course one has to show that the Hausdorff measure does give the surface area in the smooth case, which is somewhat manageable in 1D, but more nuanced IIRC in higher dimensions.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yes it isn't exactly trival that the two should agree. Of course I suppose then the question is which notion of surface area you take to be more fundamental.